# Problem with accessing virtual environment Python from R Markdown

Tags: python, r, virtualenv, pipenv, reticulate

Note: I'm on Windows using Git Bash.

So, I am trying to setup a dev environment for the work for my class. It is going to involve a combination of coding in `R` and `Python`.

I created virtual environments using `pipenv` and `virtualenv` and ran into the same problem with both. So, first, let's create a virtual environment for the project in a sub-folder `dev_env`:

```
 cd project_folder/dev_env
```

```
pipenv --python 3.7
```

```
pipenv --py
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\Ra Me\.virtualenvs\dev_env-5TUtSZI9\Scripts\python.exe
```

Now I'm going into my `file.rmd` and trying the `reticulate` package.

```
#install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
```

Next, I tried 2 methods:

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "C:/Users/Ra Me/.virtualenvs/dev_env-5TUtSZI9/Scripts")
```

or

```
use_virtualenv("C:/Users/Ra Me/.virtualenvs/dev_env-5TUtSZI9/", required = TRUE)
```

```
x = 1
if x:
    print('Hello!')
```

Both of them produced the error

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

**However, when I change the path to the `Python` environment that's installed for all users on my machine, it works.**

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "C:/Program Files/Python37/")
```

This method also works. However, here we are not even using the `reticulate` project.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine.path = list(
  python = "C:/Program Files/Python37/python.exe",
  r = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/bin/R.exe"
))
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: I ended up using Anaconda's environment management tool to create environments. I am using PyCharm and I setup virtual environments through it using Anaconda. It worked so much better. @r_alanb

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. It turns out there might be a bug in reticulate: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/801

Comment: @r_alanb check out this piece of documentation I created for setting up a project with virtual Python and R environments https://rmelikov.github.io/project_setup/